# Macro for printing of excel sheet with different value in one cell for each copy

Tags: vba, excel

I am searching for Excel macro which will change the value in specified cell for each copy while printing. It can be used for example to print 20 school assignments with different student names on it. These names are stored in the second sheet in column A in range A1:A20. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    While Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1).Value
        Sheets(1).PrintOut
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```